# How to execute a function while the page is loading with quaternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following this tutorial and slowly dawdled in my own direction. There is a list of houses, with a link-button that sends you to the page with a list of people. But when you click on the link-button through the `house` it will display the `houseId` in the url. And when the list of people loads, I want it to check whether the url has a `houseId` or not.

If it's the case where it HAS an Id, than execute `getPeopleFromHouse` which basically `axios`-calls and puts the data in `people: []` which is in the `this.state = {...}`. It's hard to formulate this question so for context here is the code that I have:

```
getPeopleFromHouse = (HouseId) => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/house/getPeople/" + HouseId)
         .then(response => response.data)
         .then((data) => {
              this.setState({people:data});
         });
}
```

And this is in the `return` of `render()`, I basically want to get rid of the buttons(add,edit,delete) when there is an Id and lastly execute the method so it only shows the people from that one house:

```
<Card.Body>
<table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody onLoad={!isNaN(parseInt(this.state.urlLastId)) === true ? this.getPeopleFromHouse(this.state.urlLastId) :
  null}> {this.state.people.length === 0 ?
  <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="{3}">{people.length} Users Available.</td>
  </tr>
  : currentPeople.map((person) => (
  <tr key="{person.PersonId}">
    <td>{person.FullName}</td>
    <td>{person.PhoneNumber}</td>
    <td>
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Link to={"addPersonToHouse/" + person.PersonId} className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Add To House </Link>
        <Link to={"editPerson/" + person.PersonId} className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Edit </Link>
        <button size="sm" variant="outline-danger" onClick="{this.deletePerson.bind(this," person.PersonId)}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </td>
  </tr>
  )) }
</table>
</Card.Body>
```

Also one last thing sorry for the formatting, but when I ctrl+v my code it just keeps formatting weirdly and I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT:
@Always Learning's solution was good, but it didn't work because I didn't make a route for it yet so I added  `<Route path={"/getPeopleFromHouse/:houseId"} exact component={PersonList}/>` and now it works :D

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. What's not working?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I want it to execute `getPeopleFromHouse(this.state.urlLastId)` if the url has a `houseId` and what that does is changing the value of `people[]` which is in `this.state={}`, but the problem is I don't know how to put it in code. And as extra the buttons shouldn't get rendered if there is a `houseId`. (in the `tbody` is the code of what I tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it better to implement logic like that before the return statement, so you can do things like this:

```
const getPeopleRow = () => {
  console.log(">>>getPeopleRow called", this.state.people.length);
  return (
  <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="{3}">{this.state.people.length} Users Available.</td>
  </tr>
  );
}

const getButtonGroup = (currentPeople) => {
  console.log(">>>getButtonGroup called",currentPeople);
  return currentPeople.map((person) => (
    <tr key="{person.PersonId}">
      <td>{person.FullName}</td>
      <td>{person.PhoneNumber}</td>
      <td>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Link to={"addPersonToHouse/" + person.PersonId} className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Add To House </Link>
          <Link to={"editPerson/" + person.PersonId} className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Edit </Link>
          <button size="sm" variant="outline-danger" onClick="{this.deletePerson.bind(this," person.PersonId)}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </td>
    </tr>
    ));
}

render() {
  let rows;
  if (this.state.people.length === 0) {
    rows = this.getPeopleRow();
  }
  else rows = this.getButtonGroup(currentPeople);
  console.log(">>>got Rows:",rows);
  return (
  <Card.Body>
  <table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody onLoad={!isNaN(parseInt(this.state.urlLastId)) === true ? this.getPeopleFromHouse(this.state.urlLastId) :
    null}> 
    { rows }
  </table>
  </Card.Body>
  );
}
```

Perhaps even move the `onLoad` handling outside to the React lifecycle methods so it's initiated when the component loads, not when the table loads.

Comment: I tried to change it and it would make sense if it worked, but if the url is `http://localhost:3000/getPeopleFromHouse/21` than it's blank and if the url is just `http://localhost:3000/people` than it works normally. (just every person in db)

Comment: I edited the answer. The functions should use => format so that `this` is bound properly

Comment: for some reason it still shows nothing. Is there a way to debug this? (react.js -> intellij)

Comment: add console.log statements so you know when the functions are called and what variables contain. I edited to include some examples of console.logs that might help. They should show in the browser's Console at runtime.

Comment: where can I find the console.log, I thought it was in the console when you click F12, but it's just yellow cookie warnings.

Comment: if you're using Chrome or Firefox, right click on the page and click "Inspect" to open the dev tools. There should be a Console tab

Comment: This is what I get in the console: https://imgur.com/a/cK9DbUr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212164/discussion-between-always-learning-and-zheng-rong-cai).